# Java for MontaVista Linux

Tags: java, linux, embedded

I have a device which runs MontaVista Linux. I am thinking of running the embedded version of Apache server on this device. I can ssh onto this device and sudo to root.

My question is, which java version can be used for MontaVista Linux. I have download every version from http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/embedded/downloads/javase/index.html and tried to execute, but I could not get any version to execute.

Here is the linux version:

```
# cat /etc/*release
MontaVista Linux 6, (.dev-snapshot-20130726)
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the archived version of `jdk 1.5.0` from this link : [Java2SE 5.0](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html). Check if that installs. If it does, perform an update to get the latest release.

To check the location of your JDK and the version, use the following syntax:

```
$which java
```

You will get an output like:

```
/opt/local/bin/java

java version "1.5.0_06"

Java(TM) 2 Runtime Environment, Standard Edition (build 1.5.0_06-b05)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 1.5.0_06-b05, mixed mode)
```

Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Can you please tell me what embedded web server are you planning to use.. ? The environment has to be set accordingly.

Comment: I am planning to use tomcat an host a few pages for use within my home network. Here is the link to embedded apache tomcat server - http://apache.cs.utah.edu/tomcat/tomcat-7/v7.0.42/bin/embed/apache-tomcat-7.0.42-embed.zip